# Running a django project with documentation based in linux on windows

Tags: python, django, linux, powershell, github

I want to run this project
https://github.com/sajib1066/django-event-management   in windows but its documentation is for linux. Please simplify the instructions for windows because I'm having trouble in setting this up. Especially since the source command is not in powershell.

[image]

Comment: setup wsl in windows if you are using windows 10/11

Comment: i doubt you need linux for this at all ... all that source is doing is activating a virtualenv ... in powershell you would just do `PS> .\.venv\Scripts\activate` after you create the virtualenv

Comment: @JoranBeasley It's showing an error like this                                                           .\.env\Scripts\activate : The term '.\.env\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\.env\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\.env\Scripts\activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: from project root, `env\Scripts\activate`

Comment: @Jarad can you please elaborate what exactly I should write in PS because it shows the error as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on Windows 10. If you're not opposed to using Windows Command Prompt, here are the steps to running this project. I don't use Powershell but if you must, see Powershell note at bottom of my answer.

1. Go here: https://github.com/sajib1066/django-event-management
2. Grab this clone link: https://github.com/sajib1066/django-event-management.git
3. Open Windows CMD prompt.
4. Change directory to a place on your computer. Ex: `cd "C:\Users\<your_user>\Downloads"`
5. Make new directory: `mkdir SO72525733 && cd SO72525733`
6. `git clone https://github.com/sajib1066/django-event-management.git`

```
 Output:
 C:\Users\Jarad\Downloads\SO72525733>git clone https://github.com/sajib1066/django-event-management.git
 Cloning into 'django-event-management'...
 remote: Enumerating objects: 2838, done.
 remote: Counting objects: 100% (32/32), done.
 remote: Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
 remote: Total 2838 (delta 5), reused 15 (delta 0), pack-reused 2806
 Receiving objects: 100% (2838/2838), 18.75 MiB | 6.82 MiB/s, done.
 Resolving deltas: 100% (1141/1141), done.
```

7. `cd django-event-management`
8. `virtualenv venv`

```
 Output:
 C:\Users\Jarad\Downloads\SO72525733\django-event-management>virtualenv venv
 created virtual environment CPython3.7.3.final.0-64 in 10271ms
   creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\Jarad\Downloads\SO72525733\django-event-management\venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\Jarad\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
     added seed packages: pip==22.0.4, setuptools==62.1.0, wheel==0.37.1
   activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
```

9. `venv\Scripts\activate`
10. You should see your terminal add (venv) to the path. That's how you know your virtual environment is activated in the terminal.
    Ex: *(venv) C:\Users\Jarad\Downloads\SO72525733\django-event-management>*
11. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
12. `python manage.py migrate` (or just `manage.py migrate` works too if you're in the root directory)
13. `python manage.py createsuperuser`
14. `python manage.py runserver`

**If you must use Powershell**, activating the virtual environment is no different.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd C:\Users\Jarad\Downloads\SO72525733\django-event-management
PS C:\Users\Jarad\Downloads\SO72525733\django-event-management> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\Jarad\Downloads\SO72525733\django-event-management


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----          6/7/2022  10:09 AM                .idea
d-----          6/7/2022  10:15 AM                events
d-----          6/7/2022  10:15 AM                event_management
d-----          6/7/2022  10:09 AM                static
d-----          6/7/2022  10:09 AM                templates
d-----          6/7/2022  10:10 AM                venv
-a----          6/7/2022  10:09 AM           1972 .gitignore
-a----          6/7/2022  10:16 AM         294912 db.sqlite3
-a----          6/7/2022  10:09 AM            657 manage.py
-a----          6/7/2022  10:09 AM            692 README.md
-a----          6/7/2022  10:09 AM            336 requirements.txt


PS C:\Users\Jarad\Downloads\SO72525733\django-event-management> venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) PS C:\Users\Jarad\Downloads\SO72525733\django-event-management>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Do I have to run this from virtual environment every time??

Comment: I remember when I first learned about virtual environments. I think I asked the same thing. I didn't understand why it needed to be activated. A virtual environment "venv" in this example, is a directory that stores **project-specific** packages and their **versions** (ex: `Django==2.2.13`). You can see this in `requirements.txt`. If you try to install packages without activating your virtual environment first, they will save to your computer globally, not the 'venv' project folder. So short answer is, yes... if you want to keep project-specific packages in one spot. It's best-practice.